# Setting a list without writing it manually? (Python3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, integer

I'm having some issues with my python program. I need to generate a list of numbers from 1 to 100 for use inside of a variable.

```
import random
import time

tries = 0
sumcoin = 0

list = (1, 100)

def run():
        while True:
                global sumcoin
                global tries
                correct = (list)
                guessed = (list)
                if guessed == correct:
                        print (f"\033[0;32;40mCorrect Guess! It was {correct}, found after {tries} attempts.\033[0;37;40m.")
                        sumcoin=sumcoin+1
                        print (f"You guessed  {sumcoin} times Correctly!")
                        tries = 0
                        sumcoin=sumcoin+1
                time.sleep(1)
                tries=tries+1
run()
```

The code is intended to generate a number from 1 to 100, guess it, and if it guesses wrongly then it will restart the process I will make the variable random with random.choice() or randint. This is the snippet output:

```
user@user:~ $ python3 list.py 
Correct Guess! It was (1, 100), found after 0 attempts..
You guessed  1 times Correctly!
Correct Guess! It was (1, 100), found after 1 attempts..
You guessed  3 times Correctly!
Correct Guess! It was (1, 100), found after 1 attempts..
You guessed  5 times Correctly!
Correct Guess! It was (1, 100), found after 1 attempts..
You guessed  7 times Correctly!
Correct Guess! It was (1, 100), found after 1 attempts..
You guessed  9 times Correctly!
Correct Guess! It was (1, 100), found after 1 attempts..
You guessed  11 times Correctly!
Correct Guess! It was (1, 100), found after 1 attempts..
```

As you can see, it only guessed the exact variable "(1, 100)". I am trying to make a random number out of 100 each time a new number is guessed. I searched online for the issue, but could not find any reliable results that could help me. Any and all assistance would be really, really appreciated.

Comment: It's not very clear what you are trying to attempt, but `(1,100)` is just a tuple with two integers. Search for `range` if you want to do something with all numbers from 1 to 100, search for `randrange` if you want to pick a random number for a range.

Comment: You have shadowed the built-in list function so that's not a great start. However, your code doesn't rely on it anywhere so the problem here is that *list* never changes - meaning that *if guessed == correct* will **always** be True. Also, this code doesn't seem to be using any of the functions from the *random* module

Comment: @Hyperninja303 Please edit your question to show what you're really having trouble with

Comment: @treuss I am attempting to use all numbers (1 to 100) as a variable. Sorry, i think i forgot to include that in my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, your Python isn't very pythonic. Update your IDE to use 4-space indents instead of 8. Also the use of global here seems more like habit from another language? not sure of its purpose here

Next, your issue is that you're comparing your variables `correct` and `guessed` to each other, when you have set them to the exact same thing. You're basically saying `if "this" == "this"` for every iteration. Outside of that, your `list` isn't a list, it's a tuple containing just `1` and `100`. What you're really looking for (to answer your question) is:

`list = range(1, 100)`

You might want to use `argparse` to pass a guess to the script, and you should also set up your script with `if __name__ == "__main__"` and run it from the command line or through your IDE.